# How to Fix "Feature is not part of the schema for this Realm" in Kotlin Realm Extention

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I want to use Realm with Kotlin using this [Kotlin Realm Extention](https://github.com/vicpinm/Kotlin-Realm-Extensions) library. I have added `mavenCentral()` repository and `compile "com.github.vicpinm:krealmextensions:1.2.0"` to app.gradle.

When I run my app, I got this error:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Feature is not part of the schema for this Realm. Did you added realm-android plugin in your build.gradle`

I have tried to add `apply: realm-android` in app.gradle but it's not working (beside I think it should have been called from inside the library). I also add `Realm.init(baseContext)` in my Activity since the query action requires it.

Comment: You need to specify your plugins and your Realm version

Answer (score 1):

Your plugin order needs to be

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Comment: I rewrite plugin order like you said but it doesn't help. The `apply plugin: 'realm-android'` give an error so I should remove it.

Comment: I'd need to see a sample project then. In fact, if this is a library that uses Realm, and exposes objects that can be queried by consumers of the library, then the objects must be exposed as a RealmModule. The realm module must be provided to the configuration builder, as specified in the docs.